# Can you create a sculpting mask from an image texture?

Tags: sculpting, masking

General goal: Create a mask for sculpting from an image texture.

Specifics: I'm trying to model a 3D map from a 2D image and I want to mask out the ocean when sculpting. I've found a workaround using a Vertex Weight Edit modifier, then Shrinkwrapping to a plane. It works, but it's clunky because it requires me to update the vertex group anytime new vertices are created with dynotopo. It would be a lot easier if I could just mask out the ocean. Plus, I just really want to know if there's a way to do it.

[image: Vertex Weight Map]
[image: 2D Mask]
[image: Final version]

This is the first time I've used the sculpting tools to this extent. Part of the reason for this project was to develop my skills with this feature set, so let me know if you have any reading or tutorials you'd suggest! Thanks in advance!

I tried uploading my Blend file, but I couldn't get it lower than 89MB even without any textures. I didn't realize the mesh was that dense :/

Comment: What about using Geometry Nodes to flatten the ocean part? It's not a sculpt mask but serves the same purpose.

Comment: @Blunder sorry! I forgot to respond to this. I have thought about that, but it's not dissimilar from what I'm already doing and I was specifically wondering if there is any feature for creating sculpting masks from an image, or way to pull that off. Good suggestion though!